# Executing a block of code after all components are loaded

Tags: java, swing

I have a program which talks to serial port.
Threading is involved in this serial port program.

I am showing a swing frame to display the status of the serial port.
The problem is when I call `setVisible(true)` the window is not loading fully.
I tried using `isValid()` to start the serial port script after the window finished loading but it never worked.

I want to initiate the serial port script after the window finished loading.
How do i get over this problem ?

```
//Code used to call setVisible()

form_objects.cardPayment.setVisible(true);  
if (form_objects.cardPayment.isValid()) {  
    openPort.sendMessage(global_variables.port, "@PL\r");  
    String readMessage = openPort.readMessage(global_variables.port);  
    System.out.println(readMessage);  
    String check_bit[] = readMessage.split(",");  
    System.out.println(check_bit[2]);  
    if (check_bit[0].equalsIgnoreCase("@PL") &&check_bit[2].trim().equals("0")) {  
        card_payment.card_text.setText("Swipe Card");  
        openPort.sendMessage(global_variables.port, "@PU," + amount +  ",,,,1\r");  
        boolean loop = true;  
        while (loop) {  
            openPort.sendMessage(global_variables.port, "@SR,1,131\r");   
            readMessage = openPort.readMessage(global_variables.port);  
            if (readMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("Timeout")) {   
                card_payment.card_text.setText("Enter Pin");  
            }  
            if (!readMessage.equals("") && !readMessage.equals("Timeout"))    {  
                loop = false;  
            }  
        }  
        String sr[] = readMessage.split(",");  
        if (sr[1].equals("1") && sr[5].equals("")) {  
            System.out.println("Cancelled");  
            card_payment.card_text.setText("Payment Cancelled");  
            form_objects.cardPayment.dispose();  
        } else if (sr[1].equals("1") && sr[5].equals("T")) {  
            System.out.println("Accepted");  
            card_payment.card_text.setText("Accepted");  
            long ptime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();  
            while(ptime+10000>=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()){  
                //do nothing just stay thhere for 10 seconds  
            }  
            form_objects.cardPayment.dispose();  
        } else if (sr[1].equals("1") && sr[5].equals("F")) {  
            System.out.println("Declined");  
            card_payment.card_text.setText("Payment Declined");  
        }  
    } else {  
        System.out.println("terminal offline");  
    }  
}
```

--Code used to read and write the port which uses `thread.sleep()`---

```
public static void sendMessage(SerialPort port, String msg) {

    if (port != null) {

        System.out.println(msg);

        try {

            byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes("US-ASCII");

            try {

                global_variables.outputStream.write(bytes);

                System.out.println(bytes.length);

                global_variables.outputStream.flush();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(openPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(openPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

        System.out.println("Opened successfully:" + msg.getBytes());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);  // Be sure data is xferred before closing
            System.out.println("read called");
            //byte b[] = new byte[1024];
            //global_variables.inputStream.read(b);

            //System.out.println("available" + global_variables.inputStream.available());

            //SimpleRead read = new SimpleRead();
            //int read = global_variables.inputStream.read();
            //System.out.println("read call ended"+read);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}

public static String readMessage(SerialPort port) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count=0;                    
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);                
            if (global_variables.inputStream.available() > 0) {
                /*assigning it to count variable makes the read uniform. if we use available() each time the string are not processed fully.
                 * so assign it to count and use the count for rest of the buffer read operation
                 */

                count = global_variables.inputStream.available();
                System.out.println("Data Available:" + count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    buffer[i] = (byte) global_variables.inputStream.read();
                }
                String response = new String(buffer, 0, count);                    
                return response;
            } else {
                return "Timeout";
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(openPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(openPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    return "timeout";
}
```

When I used the following code in the place of `form_objects.cardPayment.setVisible(true)` I couldn't get the serial port methods called.
Can you guys explain me why is it happening?

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    form_objects.cardPayment.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have to wonder if your problem really is about tying up the main Swing thread, the EDT, and your need to use background threading so that your serial port code doesn't block Swing. Also, are you adding all components to the GUI before calling pack() on the top-level window?  Are you starting your Swing code on the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)? Can you tell us more about your program and show critical code?

Comment: check my edit... sorry for my poor formatting. i couldn get it right :(

Comment: `re you adding all components to the GUI before calling pack() on the top-level window?` yes i am doing that

Comment: Deekpak, one problem (that is not complete related to your question) is that your code is trying to do everything at the same time. You're mixing Swing, serial port (communication) and business logic in the same method. That a perfect (I really mean perfect) recipe for disaster.

Comment: i want to open the window and then i have to call the serial port functions to display the message onto the screen. so for that if i call the serialport from the formopened() event of the swing window will this problem be solved  ?

Comment: no its about issue how to separate GUI logic and aplications logic, in other..., GUI is one issue (with "please wait ...") and that's nothig to do with data flow via RS232, move that to BackGroung Task

Comment: @mKorbel: I solved that issue by running the application logic as a background process using SwingWorker and now its fine...

Comment: just note that if you want to use Executor.execute(SwingWorkerClass) look at Top 25 Bugs http://bugs.sun.com/top25_bugs.do , but I think that this bugs is about overload max threads opened/limited by Executor ...

Comment: @Deepak I would really like to see an SSCCE of your solution if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same thread you call `form_objects.cardPayment.setVisible(true);`, you're also calling `while (true) {` and this will tie up your Swing app until the port code is done doing its thing.

You need to read up on using background threads as you appear to be doing all on the Swing thread.  Look into using a SwingWorker object.  e.g., [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**Edit 1:**

@Deepak: if you're still stuck, consider creating and posting, perhaps even as an answer in this thread or an addendum to your question, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (please look at the link).  This may have to be a little longer than the typical SSCCE and would be a little tricky as you'll have to simulate some of the background processes -- enough to reproduce your problem -- but could help us get you a solution.

Comment: check my edit. when i included the final part of my edit my application doesnt execute the serial port part. Can you explain me why is it happening ?

Comment: thanks for that i have learned a new concept now :) but i will be happy to learn from you how the final part of my edit works :)

Comment: @Deepak: if still stuck, please see my **Edit 1:** above.